# Need syntax for parseJSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse the following:

```
[{"Student":{"student_id":"19","student_name":"Test"},"Teacher":{"teacher_id":"1"}}]
```

But I am not sure the syntax to get the value 19, Test and 1, please help.

Comment: Which language do you want to parse it in? PHP or Javascript+jQuery?

Comment: I assume he wants javascript because of the reference to parseJSON a function in jquery to parse json data.

Comment: @jen: while I didn't downvote, I disagree. The correct approach, IMO, is to downvote poor questions (that's what downvotes are there for), and check back later to see of the question's been improved. If so, remove the downvote. Downvotes aren't an attack on the OP. They're a tool to classify questions.

Comment: @jen: Yes, exactly. That's what adlawson did. Are you suggesting that every downvote be accompanied by a separate "I agree!"?

Comment: @jen I totally appreciate your sentiment and motivation, but with 3k new questions a day, there needs to be *some* standard of quality if you don't want the community to drown in badly asked questions. It is reasonable to expect that a question fulfills *some* very basic criteria. There are dozens of guides and FAQs and examples out there about how to ask a good question. It *is* okay to hammer those with a downvote who don't care enough to fulfill even the minimum standard. Also note that the OP specified *three* different technologies in the tags, including `mysql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
var test = '[{"Student":{"student_id":"19","student_name":"Test"},"Teacher":{"teacher_id":"1"}}]'; 

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(test);

console.log(obj[0].Teacher.teacher_id)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsUrN/

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
$json = '[{"Student":{"student_id":"19","student_name":"Test"},"Teacher":{"teacher_id":"1"}}]
';

$data = json_decode($json);

// You can access values like this:
$student = $data[0]->Student;
$student_id = $student->student_id;
$student_name = $student->student_name;
$teacher_id = $data[0]->Teacher->teacher_id;
```

In Javascript:

```
var json =  '[{"Student":{"student_id":"19","student_name":"Test"},"Teacher":{"teacher_id":"1"}}]
';

var data;
if (window.JSON) {
    data = JSON.parse(json);
} else {
    data = eval(json);
}

// You can access values like this:

var student = data[0].Student;
var student_id = student.student_id;
var student_name = sudent.student_name;
var teatcher_id = data[0].Teacher.teacher_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var persons = JSON.parse('[{"Student":{"student_id":"19","student_name":"Test"},"Teacher":{"teacher_id":"1"}}]');
var myStudentID = persons[0].Student.student_id;
var myStudentTest = persons[0].Student.Test;
var myTeacherID = persons[0].Teacher.teacher_id;
```

<sub><sub><sub>*I get an odd feeling that this is homework*</sub></sub></sub>